# How to parse a string which contains spaces as an argument in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A aaa

while [ "$1" != "" ];
do
        case "$1" in
                -e|--env)
                        if [ ! "$2" == "" ] && [ ! "$3" == "" ]; then
                        aaa[$2]="$3"
                        fi
                        shift
                        shift
                        shift
                        ;;
                *)
                        echo "Error"
                        shift
                        ;;
        esac

done

for K in "${!aaa[@]}";
do
        str="$str --build-arg $K=\"${aaa[$K]}\""
done

#echo $str

./test_args.sh $str
```

It is called like:

```
./multi_args.sh -e arg1 "Hello Man!" -e arg2 Bye
```

in the second script `test_args.sh`, I get the built string `str` and print the arguments.

test_args.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ "$1" != "" ];
do
        echo "$1"
        shift
done
```

it supposed to printed like this:

```
arg1
Hello Man!
arg2
Bye
```

but it prints:

```
arg1
Hello 
Man!
arg2
Bye
```

Comment: It's because `str` is a string and you word-split it in the unquoted call `./test_args.sh $str`. You have to use an array instead. Let me look for a duplicate, I'm pretty sure there is one.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I tried ./test_args.sh "$str" but it considers all as an argument

Comment: I think it should be `str+=('--build-arg' "$K=\"${aaa["$K"]}\"")` to get two separate arguments.

Comment: why is str a string?